# how to use wlfullclient.jar to enable JMX for Monitoring WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Firstly,write sample code named JMXSample.java which use MBean server;
Actuarlly, i use the example code in Oracle online docs(Listing 4-2)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jmx/accessWLS.html
Secondly,create wlfullclient.jar and copy it to classpath;
Then run command,and problem comes:

```
javac -cp . JMXSample.java
java -cp . JMXSample
```

error code:
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: t3

Please somebody tell me how to solve it,thanks.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: i thought it is not the code problem,seems that the wlfullclient.jar does not works.

Comment: Do you need the full client? Have you tried with `wlclient.jar` that is part of the weblogic install (so you know it's built correctly)? It lives in wlserver/server/lib

Comment: i also copy the wlclient.jar to the directory which the JMXSaple.class  stores, and still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case i set the $CLASSPATH value, and Linux use “:” to separated the path;
So the command come to this:

```
java -cp .:./wlfullclient.jar JMXSample
```

Comment: On windows, `java -cp .;wlfullclient.jar JMXSample`